# Will be my AdMob account suspended if I just run my app and show real ads on my test device without clicking the ads?

Tags: android, admob

I had normally used test ads for development, but I sometimes used real ads for finishing development to see that my app really works.

But I never clicked the real ads myself.

Will be my AdMob account suspended ?

Comment: My 2 cents: Your test device will not generate invalid traffic if you add the test device in the test device list (using RequestConfiguration.Builder.setTestDeviceIds() method). Even if the test device receives a real AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a clicking on the ADs from AdMob generates a **traffic**, which brings you revenue. Therefore, no click == no traffic, you should be safe as you claimed in this question.

However, to avoid generating the **invalid traffic**, there are many ways and you should try to use them all.

- Keep your ADs unit ID secret. Someone won't use it maliciously it to generate invalid traffic.
- Don't click on your ADs. Don't tell anyone (even the users of your app) to click your ADs. Make sure the ADs clicking is caused by seeing the ADs.
- Use Alpha test track to test real AD , and use different build types to switch your AD-Real-Unit-ID and AD-Test-Unit-ID

According to [this document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants), you may put these IDs in your **build.gradle** file and automatically switch your test-AD-IDs / real-AD-IDs by selecting different build types.

Here is my code in **app/build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_debug"
        resValue "string", "ad_banner_id",   "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"  // test unit id
        resValue "string", "ad_rewarded_id", "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917"  // test unit id
    }

    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "@string/app_name_release"
        resValue "string", "ad_banner_id",   "ca-app-pub-***/***"  // real ad unit id
        resValue "string", "ad_rewarded_id", "ca-app-pub-***/***"  // real ad unit id
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a relief.   I will try your suggestion, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

"When building and testing your apps, make sure you use test ads rather than live, production ads. Failure to do so can lead to suspension of your account."

This is Google's official statement, I do not have experience with testing with live ads, so I can't give you a definite answer, probably not if it was on a smaller testing scale.

Comment: **Just showing** live ads can lead to suspension ?  I've never **clicked** live ads....

Comment: I think as long as you do not click on them that you will be fine. But if they notice suspicious clicks on live ads they could suspend you.

Comment: @Yuta **Just Showing** live ads should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes,they can suspend your ad-mob account if you click continuously on that or found any suspicious activity by ad-mob team.

Comment: I've showed real ads but never **clicked** real ads.  Then will be my admob account suspended ?